# Mysql join query on two tables with multiple colums but redundant many times

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like this:

**studentanswer**

```
stuNum | quizNum | questionId | stuAnswer
------------------------------------------
2012   |    1    |     15     | optiona
2013   |    1    |     15     | optionb
2012   |    2    |     16     | optionc
2012   |    2    |     17     | optiona
2012   |    2    |     18     | optionb
```

**questionquiz**

```
quizNum | questionId | question         | correctAns
----------------------------------------------------
1       |     15     | what is sql      | optiona
2       |     16     | what is web      | optionc
2       |     17     | what is android  | optiona
2       |     18     | what is math     | optionb
```

I want to get result like this :

```
question        | correctAns | stuAnswer
-------------------------------------
what is web     | optionc    | optionc
what is android | optiona    | optiona
what is math    | optionb    | optionb
```

i want to get all the stuAnswer based on stuNum=2012, quizNum=2

i tried this code but it loop 3 times

```
SELECT b.stuNum
     , b.quizNum
     , b.questionId
     , c.question
     , c.correctAns
     , c.markQuiz
     , b.stuAnswer 
  FROM studentanswer b 
  JOIN questionquiz c 
    ON b.quizNum = c.quizNum 
 WHERE b.stuNum = 2012 
   AND c.quizNum = 2
```

this is result i got :

```
question        | correctAns | stuAnswer
----------------------------------------
what is web     | optionc    | optionc
what is android | optiona    | optiona
what is math    | optionb    | optionb
what is web     | optionc    | optionc
what is android | optiona    | optiona
what is math    | optionb    | optionb
what is web     | optionc    | optionc
what is android | optiona    | optiona
what is math    | optionb    | optionb
```

Comment: Is this multiple choice? Where are the other choices?

Comment: I'd suggest the use of joins in order to colate the two tables together.

Comment: you're selecting 7 columns, but only want to display three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join on quizNum AND questionId.

```
JOIN questionquiz c 
    ON b.quizNum = c.quizNum AND
    b.questionID = c.questionID
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets start from the beginning.

**Select the two tables, with what you want to join them on. (there's two columns in this case)**

```
SELECT * FROM studentanswer A 
INNER JOIN questionquiz B
ON A.quizNum = B.quizNum AND A.questionID = B.questionID;
```

**Select the columns you want, and where they're from**

*This should now list all three columns that you're looking for*

```
SELECT B.question, B.correctAns, A.stuAnswer 
FROM studentanswer A 
INNER JOIN questionquiz B
ON A.quizNum = B.quizNum AND A.questionID = B.questionID;
```

**Get this for a particular Student ID**

```
SELECT B.question, B.correctAns, A.stuAnswer 
FROM studentanswer A 
INNER JOIN questionquiz B
ON A.quizNum = B.quizNum AND A.questionID = B.questionID
WHERE A.stuNum = '1234';
```

**Now we want to show for their quiz number as well**

```
SELECT B.question, B.correctAns, A.stuAnswer 
FROM studentanswer A 
INNER JOIN questionquiz B
ON A.quizNum = B.quizNum AND A.questionID = B.questionID
WHERE A.stuNum = '1234' AND B.quizNum = '1';
```

And that should be it!

***Disclaimer:*** untested at present, but should be almost 100%